# Adding a .zip as a (Library/Dependency) in Visual Studios for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, zip, libraries

I am currently self-teaching myself C#, so please understand that I am very new to the language, IDE, and terminology. Up until now, I have exclusively coded in Intellij. I am trying to practice by recreating something I made in Java a while back, a League of Legends application that uses the Riot API.

For this, I used a Java Wrapper that I found on GitHub that worked wonders. I came across a very similar wrapper for C# and have been trying to figure out how to add it to my project so that it is usable in my code.

I have downloaded everything I need, I just cannot find anything on how to add something in that format. All the links that I have researched have shown how to get to the menu, but when it comes to selecting the type of reference I want, I get lost. Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: The .zip file obviously isn't the library. it *contains* the library. 1) unzip the library, 2) in solution explorer, right-click References and select Add Reference, 3) choose Browse, 4) browse to .dll file at whatever location you unzipped the library, 5) profit

Comment: @itsme86 THANK YOU I DIDN'T EVEN KNOW DLL WAS A THING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) unzip the library
2) in solution explorer, right-click References and select Add Reference
3) choose Browse
4) browse to .dll file at whatever location you unzipped the library
5) profit

Full Credit to @itsme86

This worked perfectly, just took me a minute to find the .dll file. It should be in a lib/libs folder in your project.

Comment: Don't forget, I get a share of #5. ;)